# vmware:I can't add Trusted Root Certificates, error com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.Error, Certificate bearing subject CN=xx is not a valid CA certificate

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I'm using vSphere Client version 7.0.2.00200, facing issue when adding the Trusted Root Certificates in administration settings.

Error message: Error occurred while adding trusted root certificates: com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.Error, Certificate bearing subject CN=XXXXX,O=XXXXXXXXXXX,L=Palo Alto,ST=California,C=US is not a valid CA certificate. Please retry with a valid certificate chain

Please helpme out.

Answer (score 0):

Very late but try this.

**Add cert :**

> /usr/lib/vmware-vmafd/bin/dir-cli trustedcert publish --chain --cert

/root/DARootCAX3.pem

**Vérify :**

> /usr/lib/vmware-vmafd/bin/dir-cli trustedcert list

**Refresh :**

> /usr/lib/vmware-vmafd/bin/vecs-cli force-refresh

**restart services :**

> service-control --stop --all
>
> service-control --start --all